# Eclipse: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, eclipse

After incorrect shutting down of the laptop (and, as a result, Eclipse), I cannot start my Eclipse project. It says:

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.prj.MainConsole

Also, the red asterisk appears in the Project Explorer, though Build Path and all classes are fine.

Comment: Have you `Project` > `Clean...`?

Comment: If this ever happens to you and you cannot open Eclipse due to the error, you can use the `-clean` command line argument.

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning your project by clicking Project > Clean.